# Plain TeX and Italic Thorn and Eth Needed

Tags: plain-tex, italic

I am in need of italic versions of Thorn and Eth.  I can access these Old English characters using the following:

```
\font\specialfont=ecrm1000 scaled 1100 
\def\thorn{{\specialfont\char254}} 
\def\Thorn{{\specialfont\char222}} 
\def\eth{{\specialfont\char238}} 
\def\Eth{{\specialfont\char208}}
```

Is there a method for getting italics versions?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\font\specialfont=ecrm1000 scaled 1100 
\def\thorn{{\specialfont\char254}} 
\def\Thorn{{\specialfont\char222}} 
\def\eth{{\specialfont\char238}} 
\def\Eth{{\specialfont\char208}}

\font\specialfonti=ecit1000 scaled 1100 
\def\thorni{{\specialfonti\char254}} 
\def\Thorni{{\specialfonti\char222}} 
\def\ethi{{\specialfonti\char238}} 
\def\Ethi{{\specialfonti\char208}}

\thorn \thorni

\bye
```

Comment: In words: "If you get some upright characters from font `ecrm1000`, you may get the corresponding italic characters from `ecit1000`."

Comment: @Mico and get them more easily by using latex and `\textit{\th}` :-)

Comment: Absolutely! :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Isn't `\th` theta, not thorn?

Comment: @BrettReynolds no it is defined as `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FE}{\th}` and U+00FE is `LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN`